# Отрисовка линий

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter, qcursor

Есть необходимость:

- чтобы при отрисовки окна курсор находился в центре окна.
- чтобы нарисованное линии, при нажатой левой кнопке, перемешались за курсором.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать.

```
#include "spider.h"
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QPalette>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QRect>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QScreen>
#include <QBitmap>
#include <QColor>
#include <QColorDialog>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QString>
#include <QToolTip>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QCursor>



Spider::Spider(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    //Внешний вид окна

    Qt::WindowFlags f;//передаём значения флагов

    //type - отвечает за тип окна и задается единственным значением

    //f= Qt::Tool;
    //f=Qt::Dialog;
    //f=Qt::Sheet;
    //f=Qt::Drawer;
    //f=Qt::ToolTip;
    //f=Qt::SplashScreen;

    //hint – задает особенности отображения окна. Здесь может быть задано несколько значений, комбинируемых побитовым ИЛИ.

    f=Qt::CustomizeWindowHint; //Выключает значения флагов, заданных  по умолчанию.
    f|=Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint;//Добавляет системное меню окна, и, возможно, закрывающую кнопку.
    f|=Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint;//Добавляет кнопку сворачивания.
    f|=Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint;//Добавляет кнопку разворачивания.
    f|=Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint;//Добавляет закрывающую кнопку.
    f|=Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint;//Информирует оконную систему, что окно должно находиться поверх всех.

    this->setWindowFlags(f);


    //Состояние окна

    Qt::WindowStates st;//задание значения состояния окна

    //st=Qt::WindowNoState;
    //st=Qt::WindowMinimized;
    //st=Qt::WindowMaximized;
    //st=Qt::WindowFullScreen;
    //st=Qt::WindowActive;

    this->setWindowState(st);

    Qt::WindowStates state;//получение значения состояния окна
    state=this->windowState();

    qDebug()<<state;//Выводим значение в консоль


    //Заголовок

    this->setWindowTitle(tr("Spider"));

    //Иконка

    QIcon icon(":/res/Images_lab1/icon1.ico");
    this->setWindowIcon(icon);

    //Фон

    QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor();// открывает окно палитры
    if (!color.isValid() ) {}

    QString str = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Open Dialog", "", "*.bmp *.jpg");// открывает проводник

    QPalette palette;
    palette.setColor (QPalette::Active,QPalette::Window,QColor(color) );
    QPixmap pix (str);

    palette.setBrush (QPalette::Inactive,QPalette::Window, QBrush(pix));
    this->setPalette (palette);

    //this->setWindowOpacity(0.5); // делаем цвет полупрозрачным


    // Размер и расположение

    //this->setGeometry(100,200,700,500);// задаёт расположение верхнего левого угла и розмер окна
    //this->move(50,50);//задаёт расположение верхнего левого угла
    this->setMinimumSize(700,500);// задаёт минимальный размер окна
    this->setMaximumSize(800,600);// задаёт максимальный размер окна

    // Курсор

    //QCursor cursor= Qt::CrossCursor; //крестик
    //QCursor cursor= Qt::WaitCursor;   //кружок
    //QCursor cursor=Qt::PointingHandCursor;//рука

    //this->setCursor(cursor);

    QPixmap p(":/res/Images_lab1/super_spy.bmp");
    p.setMask(QBitmap("super_spy.bmp"));
    this->setCursor(p);


}

Spider::~Spider()
{
}



void Spider::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{

    if(event->buttons() == Qt::RightButton && event->modifiers()==Qt::ControlModifier)
    {

        qDebug() << "Нажата right button";

        //qDebug() << "относительные (клиентские) кординаты"<<event->pos();
        //qDebug() << "абсолютные(экранные)"<<event->globalPos();

        //qDebug() << "x="<<event->x();//абсолютные(экранные)
        //qDebug() << "y="<<event->y();//абсолютные(экранные)

        QString strX=QString(). setNum(event->x());// переводим число в строку
        QString strY=QString(). setNum(event->y());

        qDebug() << "x="<<strX;
        qDebug() << "y="<<strY;

        QToolTip::showText(this->mapToGlobal(event->pos()),strX+","+strY );// певое значение координаты подсказки

    }

    if(event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
       isDrawing =true;
    }
}


void Spider::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    if(isDrawing==true)
    {
        QPainter painter(this);

            QPen pen;  // перо по умолчанию

            //pen.setWidth(3); // толщина пера
            //pen.setBrush(Qt::gray); // цвет пера
            //painter.setPen(pen); // применяем настройки пера

            //рисуем паутину

            int W = width(); // Ширина окна
            int H = height();// Высота окна
            int x1 = x();// Высота окна
            //int y1 = y();

            void MainWindow::setCur()
            {
                QCursor::setPos(this->pos()+this->rect().center());
            }


            //QCursor QPoint QCursor::pos();
            //А рисовать будем в клиентских координатах. Для преобразования  экранных координат в  в оконные можно использовать:
            //QPoint QWidget::mapFromGlobal (const QPoint &pos) const

            painter.drawLine(0, H/2, p.x(), p.y());
            painter.drawLine(W/2, 0, x1, y1);
            painter.drawLine(W/2, H, x1, y1);
            painter.drawLine(W, H/2, x1, y1);
            painter.drawLine(0, 0, x1, y1);     //верхний левый угол
            painter.drawLine(W, H,x1, y1);      //нижний правый угол
            painter.drawLine(W, 0, x1, y1);     //верхний правый угол
            painter.drawLine(0, H, x1, y1);     //нижний левый угол;


    }



}


void Spider::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
     isDrawing =false;
}
```

Comment: `чтобы при отрисовки окна курсор находился в центре окна.` &&  `чтобы нарисованное линии, при нажатой левой кнопке, перемешались за курсором.` это как?

Comment: При запуске программы курсор должен появится в центре окна. К нету сходятся линии из углов окна. При нажатой левой кнопки мыши и перемещении линии одним концом "закреплены" в углах, а другим следуют за курсором.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Холст.

Голова

```
class CanvasWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CanvasWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

    // Метод установки курсора в центр холста
    void moveCursorCenter();

protected:
    // Здесь рисуем
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;

    // При движении мышки просим обновить холст
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
};
```

Тело

```
#include "CanvasWidget.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QGuiApplication> // Нужен для получения состояния кнопок мыши

CanvasWidget::CanvasWidget(QWidget *parent):
    QWidget(parent) {
    // Отслеживаем движение мышки постоянно, а 
    // не только когда нажата ЛКМ
    setMouseTracking(true);
}

void CanvasWidget::moveCursorCenter()
{
    // Помещаем курсор в центр холста
    QCursor::setPos( mapToGlobal(rect().center()) );

    // Просто обновляем (перерисовываем) холст
    // метод update - означает "Когда у вас будет такая возможность, 
    //     перерисуйте холст, пожалуйста ( мы котики )"
    // метод repaint() - означает "Отложи все дела и перерисуй холст немедля! (азм есмь Царь!)"
    // Мы просим вежливо, потому что котики
    update();
}

void CanvasWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QWidget::paintEvent(event);
    // Рисовалка
    QPainter painter(this);
    
    // рамка контента холста
    const QRect& r = rect();

    // Позиция курсора из глобальных координат в локальные
    QPoint cursorPos = mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos());

    // Если нажата ЛКМ то
    if (QGuiApplication::mouseButtons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton)) {
        // ручка - красная
        painter.setPen(Qt::red);
        // заполнение - красное
        painter.setBrush(Qt::red);

        // рисуем кружочек под кончиком курсора
        painter.drawEllipse(cursorPos, 2, 2);
    } else {
        // Иначе ручка черная и прерывистая
        painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt::black), 1, Qt::DashLine));
    }

    // Линии из всех углов холста в локальные координаты курсора
    painter.drawLine(r.topLeft(), cursorPos);
    painter.drawLine(r.topRight(), cursorPos);
    painter.drawLine(r.bottomLeft(), cursorPos);
    painter.drawLine(r.bottomRight(), cursorPos);

}

void CanvasWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);    
    update();
}
```

Запускаем:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include "CanvasWidget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    CanvasWidget w;
    w.show();
    w.moveCursorCenter();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Запускабельно!

Comment: Огромное. Спасибо!!!